# Error-Receiving error while executing test scripts in VSC webdriver-io

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, webdriver-io

2022-10-06T04:58:42.199Z ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't find plugin "allure" reporter, neither as wdio scoped package "@wdio/allure-reporter" nor as community package "wdio-allure-reporter". Please make sure you have it installed!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opKsg.png)

Comment: have you install "wdio-allure-reporter", when initialize your project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes i have included the allure report